# regex get any amount of characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i have that string :

```
[START]     john  gregor  max  [END]
```

So what i need is to extract only the names : john gregor and max and avoid the spaces , i have marked my string range by START and END so you can understand where the spaces begin and end.

NOTE : [START] and [END] does not exist in the string , i just added it to explain more.

Or

```
string text = "     john  gregor  max  ";
```

Comment: I guessed you're using .NET regexes based on your history and re-tagged accordingly.  Please let me know if my guess is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `[^\s]+`  : http://regexr.com?31k0e
2. `[A-Za-z]+`  : http://regexr.com?31k0h
3. Do not use regex, just split your string on whitespace.

Comment: Thank you so much , first answer was exactly what i needed.

Comment: `\S` can also be used instead of `[^\s]`. And let's hope you never encounter a `Renée` or a `Bärbel`.

Comment: String varString ="     john  gregor  max  ";                     String [] varArray=varString.trim().split(" ");

Comment: @Saurabh: You should post that as an answer. It is the best one so far.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the code is in java

```
String varString ="     john  gregor  max  ";
String [] varArray=varString.trim().split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while( $string =~ /(\w*)(.*)/ ) # repaired, was: /(\w)(.*)/
{
    $name = $1;
    $string = $2;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer , i do not use PHP :) but i assume it is right.

Comment: This will only find the first letter of the first word with the first group (and throw the entire rest of the string into the second group).

Comment: Now it will only find the first word.

Comment: that's the purpose, to iterate until there is no word